# Angular2 How to put a indexed object array in matrix url?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a object with the JSON string value of

```
"{"profile":[{"slug":"valentin-ozich","type":"person"},{"slug":"ian-paley","type":"person"},{"slug":"black-scale","type":"brand"}],"source":"123","from":"333","to":"566"}"
```

When I pass it to router-link like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/sth', obj]">
    Test
</a>
```

The src it renders is: 
`/sth;profile=%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D;source=123;from=333;to=566`

What should I do or process the object first so that it renders arguments into matrix url properly? Or does Matrix URL support indexed object array?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try to pass something like `{ profile: JSON.stringify(array) }`. Then extract the `profile` and parse it back to an object. Or `{ data: JSON.stringify(obj) }` and extract `data` from the params

Answer (score 0):

Store that object as a real object, not stringified..

In code, do it like this:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(YOUR-JSON-STRING-HERE);
```

In your Template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/sth', obj.profile]">
    Test
</a>
```

Comment: No it is a JS object, I was just mentioning its value as JSON